# how to set meta tag logic in .ctp file in cakephp?

Tags: php, html, css, cakephp

### I try to this code into cakephp code...

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta content="IE=edge,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
```

I try this

```
$this->Html->meta(array('charset'=>'utf-8'));
$this->Html->meta(array('content'=>'IE=edge,chrome=1'), array("http-equiv" => X-UA-Compatible));
$this->Html->meta("viewport", array("content" => width=device-width,initial-sacale=1.0));
$this->Html->meta("description");
$this->Html->meta("author");
```

but it not working...............

I am a new for cakephp.... so please help me to solve this problem...

Answer (score 6):

try this -

```
echo $this->Html->meta(
    'keywords',//name
    'enter any meta keyword here'//content
);
```

so for this -

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

echo $this->Html->meta(
    'viewport',//name
    'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'//content
);
```

[docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html) for details and other options.

for `charset` - `echo $this->Html->charset('ISO-8859-1');`

try -

```
echo $this->Html->meta(array('name' => 'viewport', 'content' => 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0',  'http-equiv' => "X-UA-Compatible"));
```

Comment: how can set http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" ?

Comment: I see no reason why a static html code be written using php.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?= $this->Html->meta(
    false,
    'ie=edge',
    ['http-equiv' => 'x-ua-compatible']
    );
    ?>
```

.... resulted

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge"/>
```

Comment: this does not produce the outcome that was asked for.